# How can I specific the operating system tag in my setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-wheel

I want to distribute my python package, so I use `setup.py` and `bdist_wheel`. I am able to specific package name and version, but the filename generated is like `package_name-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl`. I haven't figured out how to specify the `none` and `any` in the file_name with setpy.py. I need this to distribute different package versions for diffferent operating systems and CUDA versions.

My code did work in this way:

```
    setuptools.setup(
    '''
        platforms=['linux_x86_64'],
    '''
    )
```

which argument should I specify to replace the `none` and `any`?

Comment: I didn't find any way to solve my problem.

Comment: you can use `os.uname()` documentation -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.uname

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-wheel%5D+tags

Comment: https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/blob/48db0c0d0ecb4598d1a6400710445b85d67616bf/setup.py#L11-L27